# Add Current User To Admin Group

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to get the current user and add them to the Administrator Group.  So far I'm able to get the current user and pass them to the Admin add, but I'm not sure how to call it with Admin credentials in order to actually add them.

```
$user = [Environment]::Username
$group = [ADSI]("WinNT://"+$env:COMPUTERNAME+"/administrators,group")
$group.add("WinNT://$env:USERDOMAIN/$User,user")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working solution:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential ("$env:COMPUTERNAME\Administrator")
$User = $env:USERNAME
$Domain = $env:USERDOMAIN
Invoke-Command -Computername localhost -Cred $Cred -ScriptBlock {
    param ($User, $Domain, $ComputerName)
    $Group = [ADSI]("WinNT://$ComputerName/Administrators,Group")
    $Group.add("WinNT://$Domain/$User,user")
} -ArgumentList $User, $Domain, $ENV:COMPUTERNAME
```

Comment: how does one implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it, because to use ADSI with alternate creds - you need to send them in plain text:

```
$Local = New-Object -TypeName ADSI -ArgumentList @(
    "WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME/Administrators,group",
    $AdminUser,
    $AdminPass                           
)

$Local.Add("WinNT://$env:USERDOMAIN/$env:USERNAME")
```

Username usually takes form of domain\user (or $env:ComputerName\User).

Wouldn't it be better to do it other way around? Check from user account who is logged on and add this account? There few ways to get there (including tricks like checking owner of explorer.exe process).

HTH
Bartek

Answer (score 0):

This might not work for the current user, but for a generic user or group you can use  Powershell Remoting (WinRM) and the [Invoke-Command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx) and the net.exe program to add users as administrators to multiple computers:

```
icm -ScriptBlock {& "$env:SystemRoot\system32\net.exe" localgroup Administrators /add AccountName} -ComputerName server1,server2,server3
```

where **AccountName** is an AD User or Group and **Server1,Server2,Server3** is a list of computers you want to run the script block on. This won't work for the current user since you have to be an Administrator to use WinRM, but it helps when you need to add another user or group as admin to a server.

If you don't have WinRM enabled, you can use [PSEXEC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553%28v=msdn.10%29.aspx) to enable it remotely

> psexec -s \Server1 cmd /c "winrm quickconfig -quiet"